# Expression Evaluation in C++

Tags: c++, regex, expression-evaluation

I'm writing some excel-like C++ console app for homework.
My app should be able to accept formulas for it's cells, for example it should evaluate something like this:

```
Sum(tablename\fieldname[recordnumber], fieldname[recordnumber], ...)

tablename\fieldname[recordnumber] points to a cell in another table, 
fieldname[recordnumber] points to a cell in current table
```

or

```
Sin(fieldname[recordnumber])
```

or

```
anotherfieldname[recordnumber]
```

or

```
"10" // (simply a number)
```

something like that.
functions are Sum, Ave, Sin, Cos, Tan, Cot, Mul, Div, Pow, Log (10), Ln, Mod

It's pathetic, I know, but it's my homework :'(

So does anyone know a trick to evaluate something like this?

Comment: Pathetic as you may consider it to be, it is homework, and it was intended for you to learn. You should try to design a solution based on the concepts you have already been taught. Having an expert's solution will have you pass the assignment but your learning from the problem will be limited.

Comment: Or at least be smart enough not to mention it's homework :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, nice homework question by the way.

It really depends on how heavy you want this to be. You can create a full expression parser (which is fun but also time consuming).

In order to do that, you need to describe the full grammar and write a frontend (have a look at lex and yacc or flexx and bison.

But as I see your question you can limit yourself to three subcases:

- a simple value
- a lookup (possibly to an other table)
- a function which inputs are lookups

I think a little OO design can helps you out here.

I'm not sure if you have to deal with real time refresh and circular dependency checks. Else they can be tricky too.

Answer (score 2):

For the parsing, I'd look at Recursive descent parsing. Then have a table that maps all possible function names to function pointers:

```
struct FunctionTableEntry {
    string name;
    double (*f)(double);
};
```

Comment: Yay for recursive descent parsing!  I think in C++ I'd rather use inheritance and polymorphism than function pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You should write a parser. Parser should take the expression i.e., each line and should identify the command and construct the parse tree. This is the first phase. In the second phase you can evaluate the tree by substituting the data for each elements of the command.

Answer (score 1):

Previous responders have hit it on the head: **you need to parse the cell contents, and interpret them**.

StackOverflow already has a whole slew of questions on building compilers and interperters where you can find pointers to resources. Some of them are:

- [Learning to write a compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/learning-to-write-a-compiler) (#1669 people!)
- [Learning Resources on Parsers, Interpreters, and Compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41785/learning-resources-on-parsers-interpreters-and-compilers)
- [What are good resources on compilation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153330/what-are-good-resources-on-compilation)
- [References Needed for Implementing an Interpreter in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294852/references-needed-for-implementing-an-interpreter-in-c-c)
- ...

and so on.

*Aside: I never have the energy to link them all together, or even try to build a comprehensive list.*

Comment: ++ I've personally written some.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you cannot use yacc/lex (or the like) so you have to parse "manually":
Iterate over the string and divide it into its parts. What a part is depends on you grammar (syntax). That way you can find the function names and the parameters. The difficulty of this depends on the complexity of your syntax.

Maybe you should read a bit about [lexical analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis).