# Building command line applications

Tags: c++

How can I move away from (in c++) the annoying menus like:

(a) Do something
(b) Do something else
(c) Do that 3rd thing
(x) exit

Basically I want to be able to run the program then do something like "calc 32 / 5" or "open data.csv", where obviously I would have written the code for "calc" and "open". Just a shove in the right direction would be great, I am sure I can figure it all out, I just need something to google-fu.

Comment: You want to write an interpreter? Lots of resources around here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/learning-to-write-a-compiler and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294852/references-needed-for-implementing-an-interpreter-in-c-c. If this is your question that second link is a duplicate.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41785/learning-resources-on-parsers-interpreters-and-compilers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pick up [The C++ Programming Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C%2B%2B_Programming_Language), which is *the* book on C++ (there are others, but this one is great). It has an example program, spread over a few chapters, on tokenizing, parsing arguments, and making a calculator.

Comment: I have that book! (In white hardback with 2 ribbon bookmarks no less!). It was waay beyond me in the first chapter and just couldnt get into it, but it may be time to give it another go.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
string cmd;
cout << "Enter your command:" << endl;
cin >> cmd;
if(cmd == "open") {
    // read file name and open file
} else if (cmd == "calc") {
    // read and evaluate expression
} ...
```

Though depending on how complex you want your command language to be, a more elaborate design (maybe even using a parser generator) might be appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a command line parser.  I can't remember the name, but there is actually a design pattern to this.  However, [this site](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/cmdlineparser.aspx) gives you some sample code you can use to write one.  Hope that's not giving you too much of the answer :)

Comment: I'm not sure he does want a command line parser; he's wanting to input commands after the program is running.

Comment: Ah you're absolutely right, I misread that.  I know there is a design pattern for this though...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking for input like a, b, etc, just ask for generic input. Split the input at spaces, do a "switch" on the first one to match it up to your function calls, treat the rest as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Is your menu based on a call to `getchar()`?  If you want to allow entering an entire line before processing it, you can use `fgets()` or, in C++ land, `std::getline`.

Answer (score 0):

Some folks will package their C++ class definitions as Python classes by adding a Python interface to the C++.

Then they write the top-level interpreter in Python using the built-in `cmd` library.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to:

- [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) which is a very good and easy parser which also generates code on [C++](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Code+Generation+Targets).
- You can take a look to [Natural CLI](http://naturalcli.sourceforge.net/) (java) to get inspired. (Disclaimer: i'm the developer of that project).