# Write a programming language interpreter

Tags: c++, interpreter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [References Needed for Implementing an Interpreter in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294852/references-needed-for-implementing-an-interpreter-in-c-c)

How do I write a programming language interpreter such as how PHP works, im not talking about compilers though, are there any simple examples that can get me started writing a programming language interpreter?

Comment: Buy a book. The dragon book is old, but it starts from the very basics, without being in any way dumbed-down.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [boost.spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/home/) - its a good place to start.
(in particular - the [writing parsers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi.html) section of the docs)

Answer (score 1):

By no means a trivial amount of work if you are talking about a full featured programming language but of course doable with [parsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser_generator) and [lexical analyzer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_lexical_analyser) such as flex